# SQL PIVOT with a Date column

Tags: sql, datetime, pivot

I have this sample data (only subset presented)

```
Task Name   Start Date
---------   ---------- 
Task 1      2018-10-01
Task 2      2018-05-06
Task 3      NULL
Task 4      2018-10-05
```

I would like to see this output

```
Task 1      Task 2      Task 3      
------      ------      ------      
2018-10-01  2018-05-06  NULL
```

I tried the following -

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT [Task Name],[Start Date]
  FROM [TABLENAME]) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX([Start Date])
FOR [Task Name] in (['Task 1'],['Task 2'],['Task 3'])
) AS PivotTable;
```

But it doesn't work. Help appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how many rows you'll have to `PIVOT` ?.. If not you may have to use a dynamic `PIVOT`.

Comment: If you are asking whether I know which Task Names I want to have as columns, the answer is yes. I will know those names in advance. But I wont know the number of rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I'm thinking the `FOR` statement is wrong.  Try removing the single quotes:

```
FOR [Task Name] in ([Task 1], [Task 2], [Task 3])
```

When you include single quotes, they are part of the name.  And they really aren't part of the name.

Comment: Thanks!! That was it. Appreciate the quick answer!